# Get all data where 2 string from 2 table are same

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

`tb_doc` :

```
===========================================
| id | document_title | document_summary  |
===========================================
| 1  | a data mining  | document_summary1 |
| 2  | B              | document_summary2 |
===========================================
```

`tb_wrap` :

```
============================================
| id | data_url | data_title    | doc_url  |
===========================================
| 1  |data_url1 | B             | doc_url1 |
| 2  |data_url2 | a data mining | doc_url2 |
============================================
```

I wanna join data from 2 table where `document_title` = `data_title` (match 2 strings), so I will get the result like :

```
data_title <href data_url>
doc_url
document_summary
```

here's the query :

```
SELECT * from tb_wrap as a 
JOIN (
SELECT document_title, document_summary from tb_doc) as b` 
ON a.data_title LIKE b.document_title
```

How to get them? thank you :)

Comment: I removed the irrelevant PHP tag. I assume you are working with MySQL?

Comment: yes, thank you, I am working with MySql and PHP to show the result :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JOIN` condition should be an `=` rather than a `LIKE`. I see no need to join against a subquery. This is just a rudimentary `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  tb_wrap.data_url,
  tb_wrap.data_title
  tb_wrap.doc_url,
  tb_doc.document_summary
FROM 
  tb_doc
  INNER JOIN tb_wrap ON tb_doc.document_title = tb_wrap.data_title
```